# Remove duplicate column values

Tags: r, dataframe, unique

I've looked at a few posts, but can't see a clear explanation of solving this problem in R:

df looks as follows:

```
df>
  one two three
1 EC1 EC1   EC2
2 EC2 EC2   EC3
3 EC1 EC1   EC1
```

I want a new column which contains the unique values within each row as below.
Note four will have varying lengths

```
  one two three    four
1 EC1 EC1   EC2 EC1 EC2
2 EC2 EC2   EC3 EC2 EC3
3 EC1 EC1   EC1     EC1
```

From reading threads, seems like lapply formula is needed. I am also thinking a first stage would be to paste all row values into a single value in new column as a first step.

Comment: hi David - I wanted to thank you for editing the question so it appeared how I wanted it to look.I couldn't see a way paste in the dataframe from R without saving an image and uploading - it would be useful to know how for future reference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `apply` with `MARGIN = 1` to loop over the rows, get the `unique` elements and `paste` them together.

```
df$four <- apply(df, 1, FUN = function(x) paste(unique(x), collapse=" "))
```

---

We could also use `regex` with `paste` to do this

```
trimws(gsub("(\\b\\S+\\b)(?=.*\\1)", "", do.call(paste, df), perl = TRUE))
#[1] "EC1 EC2" "EC2 EC3" "EC1"
```

Comment: outstanding! Very helpful and greatly appreciated.